# How to prevent by creating case from perticular email address (email-to-case)?

Tags: email2case

Any emails from Business Intelligence usersnotallowed@invalidemail.com to toaddress@onemail.com mailbox should not create an email to cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Email Services to check the `From Address` before creating a Case.

The below example checks the From Address before creating a contact.

[image]

Details [here](https://focusonforce.com/configuration/salesforce-email-to-case-example/)

Answer (score 1):

As per Salesforce docs:

> 2) Cases should not be created when emails are received from certain
>   email addresses/domains.
>
> - On-Demand Email to Case does not have an option to blacklist or block certain email address/ domains. If emails from certain email
>     addresses/domains should not create cases, it is best to setup a rule
>     on the mailbox on which forwarding to the email to case service
>     address is setup. This step will have to be performed by the internal
>     IT helpdesk of the customer's organization.

So you can write some trigger to manually delete these records after creation or setup a rule to don't forward email address.

[How to filter creation of cases in Email to Case](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175832&type=1)